# MVC4 Bundling Version control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I'm using Asp.Net MVC4 bundling on my website. But are there an way to do any version control, so then i release an new version i can change the version number and force an refresh in the client browser?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

```
v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81
```

The query string **v** has a value token that is a unique identifier used for caching. As long as the bundle doesn't change, the ASP.NET application will request the bundle using this token. If any file in the bundle changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework **will generate a new token**, guaranteeing that browser requests for the bundle will get the latest bundle.

Comment: Search for "Bundle Caching" in that page for the section that @webdeveloper was talking about.